# Browser drops POST when Apache KeepAlive is on

Tags: javascript, apache, keep-alive

For many years I have had apache keep-alive turned on for performance reasons. It allows connections to be reused and makes my pages load subtly faster. However, in the last several months a strange issue has started to happen.

Sometimes, a connection from a user's browser to my application gets dropped which causes data to not get saved and an error to be presented.  I have done a considerable amount of testing and think that I have narrowed the problem down.  It doesn't matter which browser I use. The database and server side scripting are not a factor. It only happens with POSTs not with GETs which is interesting.  It goes away if I disable keep-alive.

Here is what I think is happening.  I have KeepAliveTimeout set to 1 second. After 1 second, the server terminates the connection but it takes a short amount of time (lets say 100ms) for the client to realize it was terminated.  So, between 1 second and 1.1 seconds, if the client attempts to reuse the connection and POST some data, that POST will fail.  I've reproduced this by making a script that POSTs some data exactly at 1 second intervals, and I can see every other connection from the client getting dropped. If I change the script to POST at 0.9 second intervals or 1.1 second intervals it never drops a connection because the specific timing window is avoided.  If I change KeepAliveTimeout to 2 seconds or some other number, then it just pushes out the timing window and doesn't really solve the problem.

My POSTs are coming from javascript (jquery.ajax), but I imagine it could happen from a regular form POST as well if you got the timing right.

In Safari and IE, the connection gets immediately dropped and fails. In Firefox and Chrome the browser stalls for dozens of seconds and then re-sends the request on a new connection which succeeds.

If this is just a fundamental problem with keepalive it is confusing to me why this worked for years and only started doing this in the last few months. Temporarily, I have disabled keep-alive, but I would like to find a way to use it if possible.  And I am hoping that someone here knows of a solution.

Comment: We came across the exact same issue today. Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Yes. We turned KeepAlive off :)  We could not find a solution. It appears to be a fundamental issue with KeepAlive and POST.  One thing we considered was having all POSTs go to a single server with KeepAlive off, and have everything else go to the servers with KeepAlive on. This ended up being too much complexity for a minor (if any) optimization.

Comment: ran into this issue as well

Comment: It's a well-known problem with Safari, and by default NGINX disables keepalive for the Safari family of browsers (not sure if that still holds true):

https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/485470
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5760

But that it happens with other webservers is new to me. The scary thing is that this seems to be a problem that started surfacing 7 years ago, but I'm seeing it happen here on a faily modern setup (as of june 2016): NGINX 1.8.0, Safari 9.1 on El Capitan.